# Is it possible to preserve the values of variables in a declare section of an anonymous PL-SQL block ran from an execute immediate statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql

If I have PL-SQL code of the following form:

```
DECLARE
  v_glob VARCHAR2(4000) := q'<
  DECLARE xyz VARCHAR2(7); BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test45654645'); END;
  >';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_glob);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (v_glob);
  -- What was the value of xyz here?
END;
```

Is there any way to cheat scope and retain those values? For my purposes, it would be permissible to add extra code into v_glob if it could be done in a regular way.

The Oracle documentation certainly makes it seem as if this isn't possible, and as I understand it, it's not supposed to be. Is there a clever workaround that I'm not seeing?

Comment: What is the problem that you're trying to solve?  `xyz` exists within the nested PL/SQL block.  It does not exist outside the block.  But even inside the block, its value is never set to anything other than the default `NULL`.  Depending on the problem you want to solve, perhaps you don't want to declare a variable inside the dynamic block.  Perhaps you want to declare it in the outer block and pass it in as a bind variable to the dynamic block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE
  v_glob VARCHAR2(4000) := q'<
  DECLARE 
    xyz VARCHAR2(7) := 'hidden!'; 
  BEGIN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test45654645'); 
    :output := xyz;
  END;
  >';
  v_output varchar2(7);
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_glob);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (v_glob) using out v_output;
  -- What was the value of xyz here?
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_output);
END;
```